# Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when using -Certificate

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, amazon-web-services

When trying to use Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell with the -Certificate parameter for using client certificates I am receiving an error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. 
At C:\Windows\Temp\PO_WorkingDir_11a96bd3-e2b3-4016-b2b8-5977c92d0bdc\PO_PSScript_11a96bd3-e2b3-4016-b2b8-5977c92d0bdc.ps1:11 char:4
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -uri "$a1/tenants/$a2" -Headers $headers -Certificate C:\Us...
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException    
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The same script works locally, but inside the Accenture tool it throws the above error.
Script:

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -uri "$a1/tenants/$a2" -Headers $headers -Certificate C:\Users\env1.ciac.pouser.AWSVA1011\Desktop\iapiclient-cpo.acp.env1.acp.aws.accenture.com\iapiclient-cpo.acp.env1.acp.aws.accenture.com\iapiclient-cpo.acp.env1_CERT.pem -ContentType application/json -Method GET
```

Am I doing something wrong here? The tool works off an application user and all scripts run against this user which is an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into the same issue and found that it may be caused by the script not running under and "Elevated" session that has Administrator privileges. Just because the user is an Administrator does not mean the script is always run with admin rights. You can add the following in your script to detect if you currently have admin rights:

```
function Test-IsLocalAdministrator {
    $identity  = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $principal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal( $identity )
    return $principal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}
```

The issue appears to be that you do not have rights to the private key of the certificate you are using. In our case we were using the Machine certificate to setup two way TLS authentication, and non-administrative users did not have rights to the PrivateKey property.

```
$ValidAt = [DateTime]::Now
$certs = @(gci Cert:\LocalMachine\My | ?{$_.NotBefore -lt $ValidAt -and $_.NotAfter -gt $ValidAt -and $_.Subject -eq ("CN={0}" -f [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computername).HostName)})
$Cert = $certs | sort NotAfter -Descending | select -first 1
$Cert.PrivateKey #This would return $null for non-admins
```

The `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` error message provided by Invoke-WebRequest is pretty generic, but in this case it probably means the current session does not have access to the private key.

Try running the script as an administrator or explicitly granting rights to the private key to the user account.